# Macro Cell Offset Based on Font?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a cell offset based on font name in VBA, but for some reason it's not working. The plan is if the font is Ariel then copy the cell into the previous column. It runs but nothing happens?

```
Sub FontOffset()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B:B")
If cell.Value = cell.Font.Name = "ARIAL" Then
cell.Offest(0, -1).Value = cell.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks,

J

Comment: Do you **really** want to look at every cell in column B from B1:B1048576?

Comment: Looking in column B from 1:18447 so it seemed simpler to do B:B

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean font name *Arial*? Also, `cell.Value = cell.Font.Name = "ARIEL"` is not valid, try `cell.Font.Name = "ARIEL"`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I adjusted it in my macro but not the post - still getting nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
If cell.Value = cell.Font.Name = "ARIEL" Then
```

The above statement resolves to *'cell.Font.Name = "ARIEL" will be True or False; if cell value is True or False then enter If statement'*. Further, since string comparison is case sensitive and the Ariel font is commonly proper case then this will never be true.

Try it as,

```
If UCase(cell.Font.Name) = "ARIEL" Then
```

On a related subject, you are examining **every** cell in column B from  B1 to B1048576. Pare it down to the worksheet's UsedRange so you don't waste time examining blank cells.

```
Sub FontOffset()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If UCase(cell.Font.Name) = "ARIAL" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, tried swapping that line however get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: You misspelled **Offest** and my Excel uses **Arial**, not **ARIEL**.

Comment: Jeez, your totally right. It was offset that messed it up. Thanks so much everyone for your help - turns out the real problem is my brain's not on!

Comment: .. or you are just day-dreaming about Disney mermaid princesses.